# Xpath if contains

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to extract value if specifig tasg contains specific text.

Input:

```html
<section class='question-other-answers'>

 <article>
  <div class='user' </div>
  
  <div class='details'> 
  
   <p class='content'>
    exampleXYZexample
   </p> 
  </div>
  
  <div class='info'>
   <div class='rating'>

    <div class='rate-up'>

     <a>123456789</a>

    </div>
    
    <div class='rate-down'>

     <a>123456789</a>

    </div> 
   </div>

  </div>
  

 </article>


</section>
```

What I want to do is:
extract every `rate-up` value if `<p class='content'>` contains `XYZ`

I know how to check if content contains `XYZ`

```
//section[@class='question-other-answers']/article/div[2]/p and contains (.,'XYZ')
```

And I know how to get `rate-up` value

```
//section[@class='question-other-answers']/article/div[3]/div/div[1]/a
```

But I have no idea how to combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A predicate can contain a node check so

```
//section[@class='question-other-answers']/article[div[2]/p[@class = 'content' and contains (.,'XYZ')]]/div[3]/div/div[1]/a
```

is a way to combine the expressions.

Comment: Hmm it's not working properly. It's extracting no matter there is `XYZ` in `content` or not. Try on this: http://pastebin.com/T2jLmtNw

Comment: @audiophonic, see the edit, it is not quite clear which elemenmts you want to identify respectively which relationship you want to check.